# vbscript utility to convert xml to json

Tags: json, xml, vbscript, hp-uft

Does anyone knows of a vbscript function to convert xml to json.
I actually found one function in vbscript that converts XML to JSON, but it works only if the xml has single element. My XML has multi elements and it's not converting to JSON correctly. Even I pass multi elements xml in request it returns only single element from it in JSON.

I'm using UFT tool to perform this task.

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Forget `VBScript`, switch to `PowerShell` to solve such kind of task.

Comment: I need this in automating my script in UFT and UFT uses VBscript. Thats why I need in VBscript. I am having hard time in parsing my XML using VBscript. I am much comfortable in parsing JSON and I have did it many times earlier for much complex json string.

Comment: Be better to write it in `Powershell`.  You can always call the `powershell` script from `UFT` using a `WScript.Shell` object's `Run` or `Exec` methods

Comment: I don't know PowerShell. If you have any function that i can use to convert xml to json then it would be of great help. Thank you.